# Run daemon process that will end when last of other processes from some group ends

Tags: ruby, linux, mutex, daemon, semaphore

I'd want to run several Ruby processes that will communicate (by HTTP) with another "service" daemon  process. Daemon process is a usual program, not a Ruby process.

Ruby processes can be started in any order. The first one will start "service" process and use it. Other Ruby processes will use it.

Daemon "service" process should die when last of Ruby processes ends (daemon process should die even if all Ruby processes would be killed).

Analogy: So daemon process should be something like a child of those several Ruby processes in terms it will die when all "parent" Ruby processes will die. Obviously, AFAIK he can't be a child of several processes.

Is it possible to do? It would be good to hear about cross-platform solution (Linux, OS X, Windows / MRI, JRuby, Rubinius).

Answer (score 0):

You bet.  Look at the [Process](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Process.html) module.  Specifically, the method [`waitpid`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Process.html#method-c-waitpid) will block a process from exiting until the given PID exits.

The docs have several examples that look like what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand how it may help me. `waitpid` works only for child processes. I don't understand which process should be a child.